# Javascript toggle menu opening but not closing

Tags: javascript

I'm in the process of learning JS and have made a collapsable navbar. I got the menu to open upon clicking the button, but it will not close. I've searched this site for answers but anything I've found refers to Bootstrap. This is just pure JS. I've also looked over my code for hours trying to spot a syntax error or anything that could be going wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
let toggleNavStatus = false;

let toggleNav = function() {
let getSidebar = document.querySelector(".nav-sidebar");
let getSidebarUl = document.querySelector(".nav-sidebar ul");
let getSidebarTitle = document.querySelector(".nav-sidebar span");
let getSidebarLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-sidebar a");

if (toggleNavStatus === false) {
    getSidebarUl.style.visibility = "visible";
    getSidebar.style.width = "315px";
    getSidebarTitle.style.opacity = "0.5";

    let arrayLength = getSidebarLinks.length;
    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        getSidebarLinks[i].style.opacity = "1";
    }

    toggleNavStatus = true;

 }

else if (toggleNavStatus === true) {
     getSidebar.style.width = "50px";
     getSidebarTitle.style.opacity = "0";

    let arrayLength = getSidebarLinks.length;
    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        getSidebarLinks[i].style.opacity = "0";
    }

    getSidebarUl.style.visibility = "hidden";

    toggleNavStatus = false;
}

}
```

Comment: You do not see an error in your browsers dev tools? Have you tried adding some `console.log('check')` lines inside of the if/else if statement to see if those parts are being triggered as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your for-loops you need to change `array.length` to `arrayLength`.

See this [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oyPOgx)

Comment: Haha, wow. I had a feeling it would be something as silly as that. Much appreciated!